# What browser does the Samsung Galaxy use?

Tags: android, browser, emulation, galaxy, samsung-mobile

Looking to check a site on a Samsung Galaxy, what browser does it use out the box and where can I emulate it - either online or on OSX?

Reason I am asking is a few CSS properties do not work and need to find a fix.

Comment: I don't think it has a name. It's just called `browser`. Not sure why though.

Comment: ha! that is a pretty crap name - their marketing people need to get the finget out.

Comment: I have experienced strange behavior in this browser specifically.  Things don't always resize right off of CSS3 window-dimensions relative sized elements, for example (if I use vmax to get the max viewport dimension, for example, it works fine in chrome, but in the Samsung Galaxy, when switching between landscape and portrait, sometimes those relatively sized elements are smaller than they should be).  I've also had backgrounds that couldn't be on the html element not take up the full height of the viewport on first load or when switching again between landscape and portrait.  Weird stuff.

Answer (score 9):

The Browser app that is present on TouchWiz (Galaxy) devices is not the stock Android (AOSP) Browser. The Samsung Browser has customizations on top of the stock browser (such as the functionality for OS/Browser-controlled elements i.e. select fields).

The bad news is that it is difficult to recreate these issues without having a TouchWiz/Galaxy device in hand. While you *can* create an [Android Virtual Device](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html) using the [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) to test the Browser, you may find that the controls are somewhat different than what are present in the TouchWiz browser.

There are [apks of the Samsung Browser app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1969991) out there, but they need to replace the existing stock browser in your device's system directory, which requires root access.

Comment: This means i can probably install one of those APKs on genymotion ?

Comment: I have not tried this, but I would be interested in the results, honestly.

Comment: Your first two sentences contradict each other.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that Linux was actually UNIX, and that Windows 98 is actually MS-DOS. The point of pedantry is usually to make two distinct concepts more distinct, not to muddle them together. Hence, Samsung Browser is not the same thing as Android Browser, just as any Chromium based browser is not the same as Chrome.