# How can I address the Samsung Android browser?

Tags: javascript, android, css, samsung-mobile

I'm working on a responsive website and **I have a weird CSS/JS issue with the default touchwiz browser of Android Samsung devices**. I've searched on StackOverflow, finding some unhelpful answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19551809/208623).

**I have the physical devices to test on**, but since it's not possible to do remote debugging on these browsers it's really time consuming to make changes, deploy them a QA server, test, and retry.

Any idea on how can I speed up my testing or targeting that specific browsers?

Useragent is not helping in my case...

Just to make an example: one of the many problems I'm facing is on this [free component](https://github.com/filamentgroup/dialog), it's not positioning in the middle of the screen, while it's ok on all other android and iOS browsers.

Comment: And none of these problems happen on the stock android browser (even older versions like the 4.1 or even 2.3 browser) I assume?

Comment: Also - in my experience [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23786275/1348195) helps tramendously. Have you tried it?

Comment: Any luck with the INFO:CONSOLE logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mobile testing, here are some resources might help.

Personally I prefer the Samsung emulator and Adobe Edge Inspect(will charge).

1. [Adobe Edge Inspect](https://creative.adobe.com/products/inspect)
2. [Samsung Emulators](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095)
3. [Chrome - Device Mode & Mobile Emulation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode) (recommended only for testing responsiveness)
4. [Keynote](http://www.keynote.com/solutions/testing/mobile-testing) (might charge fee)

Because the limit of the content length, Please click the links and see the detailed documentation.

Hope it will help to speed up the testing and debug on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a device I would suggest you to try this tool [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/)
It's allow you to remote debug. I always use it for stuff like that

Comment: videos at YouTube may be helpful: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=weinre

Comment: The main feature of this tool - it is not depends on browser. To use it you have to run weinre server, just add script on your page and open this page in any browser you nee. Go to the debug page on your computer and see what's going on. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) can take care of the JS debug. Combined with the [CSSRule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22638396/1166904) API and the following to grab the browser's default style values for an element and its current rendered values, you might be able to get somewhere.

```
function defaultStyle(tag) {
    var defaultStyles = {},
    testElem = document.createElement(tag),
    getStyle = 'getComputedStyle' in window,
    styles;

    document.body.appendChild(testElem);

    styles = (getStyle) ? window.getComputedStyle(testElem) : testElem.currentStyle;

    for (var prop in styles) {
        if (!(/^\d+$/.test(prop))) {
            defaultStyles[prop] = styles[prop];
        }
    }

    document.body.removeChild(testElem);

    return defaultStyles;
}

function currentStyle(elem) {
    var currentStyles = {},
    getStyle = 'getComputedStyle' in window,
    styles;

    styles = (getStyle) ? window.getComputedStyle(elem) : elem.currentStyle;

    for (var prop in styles) {
        if (!(/^\d+$/.test(prop))) {
            currentStyles[prop] = styles[prop];
        }
    }

    document.body.removeChild(testElem);

    return currentStyles;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Use media queries for making css based on screen lengths. It does not matter whether it is samsung or iphone browser. You can also use bootstrap libraries for it.

Comment: I can use media queries. The problem is that I want to debug on those samsung custom browsers and the question is about how to speed up that.

Comment: You didn't understand the question.